# Execute a script as root from Asterisk

Tags: bash, asterisk

I have the following `extension.conf`:

```
exten => XXX,Answer()
exten => XXX,n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/delExtHDD)
exten => XXX,n,System(/bin/sh /etc/asterisk/deletekeys.sh)
exten => XXX,n,Hangup()
```

The scripts chmod is 4755 and owned by root.

The script itself contains the following:

```
#/bin/sh
#/usr/bin/wipe -f -q /XXX
/bin/umount /media/sda/
/sbin/cryptsetup luksClose sda_crypt
```

Apparently the script is executed, but it doesn't unmount the filesystem, therefore I suggest it has no root rights.

How can I execute the script as root?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts has information about why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) for the hint to the unix stackexchange!

I compiled a C programm which can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369/16009 that executes the script as root.